# Zeno's Dichotomy Paradox or Zeno's dichotomy paradox?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

What the correct way of capitalizing that [paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)?

Zeno's Dichotomy Paradox or Zeno's dichotomy paradox?

[Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Zeno%27s%20Dichotomy%20Paradox%22) shows both versions (Zeno's dichotomy paradox is more common). Still, I would like to know the answer form a grammatical perspective.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with grammar to be honest.  Those appear to be style choices.  One could argue Zeno's Paradox Dichotomy is a title, whereas Zeno's dichotomy paradox is just a common noun.

Comment: You would have to ask Zeno.

Comment: The problem is, before I can get to Zeno to ask him, I have to go halfway to Zeno...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you are using it as a title or as a description. In this case, either would be valid.

In general, titles are given in "title case": capitalize the first letter of each "major" word but leave minor words, like articles and prepositions, with a small letter. We use title case for proper names of books, movies, and the  like, plus of some established ideas. Like, "The Taming of the Shrew", "Newton's Three Laws of Motion". etc.

Use ordinary capitalization when you are just describing something. Like, "He wrote a book about aardvarks." A description, thus lower case. "He wrote the book, 'History of Aardvarks'." The actual title, thus title case.

Sometimes we want to give a specific name to an idea. Like "the Theory of Gravity", "the Law of Supply and Demand", etc. So we use title case.

In your example, it could be intended as a title or it could be intended as a description, so either one would be acceptable.

Comment: @alexchenco And if you have to pick one, I would argue that Zeno didn't put "Dichotomy Paradox" on a title page (even in Greek), and that Newton didn't name the "Theory of Gravity" as such. I would lean toward lowercase, especially for phrases made up of words that are often used independently (dichotomy paradox, theory of gravity).

Comment: Just because Xeno and Newton didn't identify them as titles (assuming they didn't) doesn't mean that modern people don't think of them as titles. This page, https://pwg.gsfc.nasa.gov/stargaze/Sgravity.htm, from NASA refers to "Newton's theory of Universal Gravitation", not capitalizing "theory" but capitalizing "Universal" and "Gravitation".